# Ad loading (Admob) slowing down Android app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want to display ads in one of my fragments, using Admob. The fragment was loading slowly when I simply used method `loadAd()`, in `onCreateView()`. I made some research, and replaced `mInterstitialAd.loadAd( new AdRequest.Builder().build())` by

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        }, 2000);
```

The problem is that I don't feel it changed anything... The fragment is still loading slowly (I have to wait a few seconds before some TextViews and a button appear).
I also have this listener I use to reload ads every time one is displayed, but I don't think the problem comes from here (and it follows the advice given in Admob's docs) :

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener( new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use Handlers or any way to pause the main thread.

I didn't get quick the problem you are facing, before changing to :

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 2000);
```

but this will just delay your fragment to be shown.

Can you explain more the issue you have ?

Comment: I used this code block to delay the loading of the ad. I thought that the fragment would appear on screen first, then the ad would be loaded. However, the ad is still loading first, and I just get a white screen before it has finished loaded and the fragment appear.  Should I move the code to another method (other than onCreateView() ) ? Or should I just find another way to avoid being slowed down by ad's loading ?